# How can i Connect my winform app to about 200 computer with Ethernet

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapp

I have winform app(c#) with SQL database(mdf)
200 computers are connected with Ethernet
How can I install my app on all computers?
Is there a way to have the database of all systems in one pc an use the information that database gathered?

Comment: if the computer are under one domain, then you can use group policy to install the application on them. For the SQL file, you may need to install SQL Server, to manage the database on the main server, and just update the application with the server IP then update the group policy to update the computers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Some opinions :

> How can I install my app on all computers?

It is deployment issue. You can use [ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019) or other similar technology.
Check this out with system administrators for security and automation... or others sysadmin based publish solutions

> Is there a way to have the database of all systems in one pc an use
> the information that database gathered

Depending on what your application do, it is strongly recommended to install only one database server instead of attaching one by user. You must then generate the database connection parameters (connexionString) used by all users. Generally in config file.
you should also define upgrades with your update deployment strategy.